# How to configure Postgres on Amazon Linux

Tags: centos, postgresql, amazon-linux

Most tutorials were installing both postgresql and postgresql-server:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server

Installed:
  postgresql.x86_64 0:9.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1                         
  postgresql-server.x86_64 0:9.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1                        

Dependency Installed:
  postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1
```

The programs are installed here:

```
$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql


$ which postgres
/usr/bin/postgres
```

At this point, most tutorials go into `initdb` and `pg_ctl <path> start`

```
$ cd '/usr/lib'

$ service postgresql initdb
Hint: the preferred way to do this is now "postgresql-setup initdb"

$ sudo postgresql-setup initdb
[sudo] password for CORP\layne.sadler: 
Initializing database ... OK


$ systemctl enable postgresql
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postgresql.service to usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service.



$ systemctl start postgresql
[18:47:32]  /usr/bin ☯  systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-05 18:47:32 EST; 7s ago
  Process: 25559 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25553 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25562 (postgres)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
           ├─25562 /usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -p 5432
           ├─25564 postgres: logger process   
           ├─25566 postgres: checkpointer process   
           ├─25567 postgres: writer process   
           ├─25568 postgres: wal writer process   
           ├─25569 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
           └─25570 postgres: stats collector process

$ passwd postgres
```

note: `/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -p 5432`

**STUCK**

```
$postgres
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.

$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "CORP\layne.sadler" does not exist

$ sudo pg_ctl -D postgresql-setup initdb
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.

# can't seem to login as su despite other sudo commands working
```

Notes:

- The OS claims to be `rhel fedora centos` but doesn't have the `rhel-release` libraries.
- It seems like `epel-release` and `dnf` are blocked from install.
- ^^^ postgres installation instructions want the above tools.

Comment: Solutions go into the answer box at the bottom of the page.  It's perfectly fine to self-answer your own questions. Doing so would allow you to accept the answer (after a slight delay), which would mark the issue as resolved.  I will remove the "SOLVED" tagging from the title, and I suggest that you move the solution into a proper answer.

Comment: According to your output, the `postgresql` server is running and the database is already initialized (`/var/lib/pgsql/data`).  To connect to `postgresql`, try this as root:  `su -c "psql" postgres`.  This will invoke the `psql` client using the user `postgres` (IIRC, that is the default user those packages would be using).

Comment: @Kermit - is this problem still alive? Without further feedback from you this can't be conclusively answered - as it stands it's very much a dog's breakfast. We'd need to for instance see your `postgres.conf` and your `pg_hba.conf` ..

Comment: @tink i changed projects a long time ago

Comment: @Kermit  -  as there's never been an accepted answer - would you mind deleting your question, then? As it stands it's just a festering boil that `community` will percolate up for re-inspection every so often ... which is how it got *my* attention.

Comment: @tink absolutely not. how arrogant of you to ask. if it bothers you that much, then take a minute to stand up an AWS Workspace, run the lines of code, and edit the question once you have more info.

Comment: Why would I want to try and replicate a poorly described problem with a database version that has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for close to 5 years?  I can understand that you want to hang on to the reputation gained by 2 upvotes, but there's really no merit in the question as such.  And I fail to see trying to stop wasting visitor's time as arrogance on my part.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS (Community ENTerprise Operating System) is a community (re)build of RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux), with changed branding and some other details. It strives at being binary fully compatible, down to bug-for-bug. It doesn't have access to the RHEL package repositories, it uses their own.  EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) is a Fedora project that offers packages for RHEL/CentOS that RHEL doesn't carry.

I don't know where the "dnf is blocked from install" comes from. Note that in RHEL/CentOS dnf is relatively new (I believe an alternative starting with version 7), perhaps only the (legacy) yum is available? You could try `yum install dnf` if you need it. Depending on your exact version of CentOS, it might not be there at all.

The last error message you cite is quite clear: Postgres can't find/read it's configuration. Check *carefully* that the setup is done correctly. A wrong file name somewhere can derail everything.